# Overriding super class methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, signature, overriding

If subclass in objective-c wants to override a super class's method, does it have to match the return type too?

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to override a superclass method to return a different type. Doing so makes your subclass' API incompatible with the superclass' usage, so client code cannot substitute your subclass for a superclass. Bad, bad, bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it must have the same selector.

#### update:

IIRC the arguments also needs to have the same types.

#### update:

It seems that all methods of the same selector needs to have equivalent types across all classes when linking dynamically, not so with static linking: [linky](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocSelectors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH23-TPXREF130)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It be same,

But one thing to be noted is you need to pass the super-class of return types.

Eg:

```
-(UIScrollview)method:(id)argument;
```

you can return UIview as well. (simply saying super class of return types).